# Having Updatable Views that obey initial select conditions

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
+--------------+----------+-------------+
| name         | is       | in          |
|--------------+----------+-------------|
| Study        | <null>   | <null>      |
| Sport        | <null>   | <null>      |
| Biology      | Study    | <null>      |
| Linguistics  | Study    | <null>      |
| Art          | <null>   | <null>      |
+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

And I want to build a view as such:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT name FROM t WHERE "is" = 'Study';
```

Now if I want to insert into this view, it does not automatically set "is" to 'Study', I have to write a trigger and a function to adjust this behavior. However, this is a highly repeated pattern in my application, and I was wondering if there is a way to automatically achieve this (an updatable view that obeys the select condition).

Comment: You can define the table column with a  default value: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c863b976c1702207bcca42c82cdfe493

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works, it is in SQL server but concept maybe the same in your case:

If its always required you can set default. It will update always when you insert the view [is] with 'Study':

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT  df_is DEFAULT 'Study' FOR [is];
```

Or you can create another view only for insert:

```
CREATE VIEW v_insert AS SELECT name,[is] FROM t WHERE [is] = 'Study';
DECLARE @is NVARCHAR(max)='Study';
INSERT INTO dbo.v_insert (name, [is]) VALUES ('nametoinsert', @is )
```